# Connect SQLServer2008R2 with Netbeans in android emulator

Tags: sql-server-2008, android-emulator, netbeans-7, jtds

I'm trying to make a connection to a SQL Server 2008 R2 using Netbeans 7.2.1 to code into an android emulator SDK. Basically, i'm using this code:

```
package ConnectDB;

import java.sql.*;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;

public final class ConnectDB {
    public void Connect() {
        String Connectionurl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;instance=some_instance;databasename=some_database;user=some_user;password=some_password;";
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectionurl);
    }

}
```

This code is tested and works fine in a simple java application but in android project it gives NoClassDefFoundError when calling for driver. I already copied to libs dir jtds-1.3.0.jar and when I right click on Project>Properties I see on JAR libraries that this jar is included but the error persists. I already sqljdbc4.jar and different connection method but in teh end i get the same. 
The android platform is 4.2 and JRE 1.7. The server IP is a 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

What am I missing here ? Is this possible on Netbeans ? Plz need some advice...